# Complex Vectors: $E$ & $H$ field coordinate transform

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, complex-numbers

We are given an electric field (or magnetic field) described by complex phasors for the three Cartesian components,
$$ \vec{E} = E_x \hat{\imath}+E_y \hat{\jmath}+E_z \hat{k} $$
with
$$ E_x = E_{x0} e^{j\omega t + \delta_x} $$
$$ E_y = E_{y0} e^{j\omega t + \delta_y} $$
$$ E_z = E_{z0} e^{j\omega t + \delta_z} $$
where all components are at the same frequency $\omega$ but may have different phases $ \delta_x$, $\delta_y$, and $\delta_z$.

When considering just $E_x$ and $E_y$, if $\delta_x-\delta_y \neq 0$ then the polarization can be determined and the magnitude in the major and minor direction found. The tilt equation solves for that.

**Is there a generalization for 3 dimensions to find the major and minor axes and their amplitudes? If so, what are the equations?**

Comment: See Samson JC. Descriptions of the polarization states of vector processes: Applications to ULF magnetic fields. Geophysical Journal International. 1973 Dec 1;34(4):403-19 or de la Hoz, P., *et al* 2015. Classical polarization multipoles: paraxial versus nonparaxial. Physica Scripta, 90(7), p.074030.

Comment: It has to be treated in circular polarization and is a bit complicated.  It is treated in Section 10.3.2 of my textbook, "Classical Electromagnetism".